# How to subtract day from datetime from php/mysql ?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Im trying to make a add a default value to a form from a datetime from my mysql. This code works, but I want to show the next date, that is one day less than the date I get from my database. I have tried very long but with no result.. How can I subtract a day from datetime ?

```
<input type="text" name="pub" value="
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db("kalender",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 echo $data['pub'];
 ?>
">
</input>
```

Comment: So what did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very bad: I have modified check that:

```
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db("kalender",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 $dates = $data['pub'];
 $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data['pub'].' -1 day'));
 ?>
<input type="text" name="pub" value="<?php echo $date;?>" />
```

This will give you previous date of selected date.

Answer (score 1):

In mySQL you can use the DATE_ADD function to add time to a date.

In php you use date_add or date::add.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_SUB('2005-01-01 00:00:00',
    ->                 INTERVAL '1 1:1:1' DAY_SECOND);
        -> '2004-12-30 22:58:59'
```